# How can I get an html table cell that is a link to contain text and another link?

Tags: html, css, hyperlink, href, html-table

I'm trying to get a table cell that is one big href to contain two things - an icon that opens a popup (at location A), and some text that follows the cell's href (to location B).  However I can't quite get it working.

Here's the HTML I have that only works for the icon/popup:

```
<table><tr><td>
  <a href="http://www.google.com>
    <span>
      <a onclick="window.open('http://www.yahoo.com', location=no,scrollbars=no,menubar=no,toolbar=no,status=no,resizable=yes')">
        <img src="smiley.png" />
      </a>
    </span>
    Go to Google
  </a>
</td></tr></table>
```

This works fine for clicking on the smiley icon and opening the yahoo popup, but clicking on "Go to Google" doesn't do anything.

Here's the HTML I have that works for following the href:

```
<table><tr><td>
  <a href="http://www.google.com>
    <img src="smiley.png" />
    Go to Google
  </a>
</td></tr></table>
```

This follows the href no matter what I click on in the cell (which makes sense, there's only one href).

I also tried this, but clicking on the icon would both open the popup and follow the href:

```
<table><tr><td>
  <a href="http://www.google.com>
    <img src="smiley.png" onclick="window.open('http://www.yahoo.com', location=no,scrollbars=no,menubar=no,toolbar=no,status=no,resizable=yes')"/>
    Go to Google
  </a>
</td></tr></table>
```

Any help?

Answer (score 0):

You can't just have a link contain another link. Have two links, but separated. Use CSS to make them fill the cell if you have to.

Comment: No, I got it to work in another place by having code similar to the first example, but within the span building another table.  However, that put in a line break (from the <tr>) so it was across two lines.  I need it on one.